# undirected graph in swi prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Find the number of internal stability of the
undirected graph. The internal stability number of a graph is the maximum number of vertices in a graph that are not adjacent to each other.

```
reb(a,1,2).
reb(b,2,3).
reb(c,1,3).
reb(d,3,4).
reb(e,4,6).
reb(f,5,6).
reb(g,5,7).

ver(1).
ver(2).
ver(3).
ver(4).
ver(5).
ver(6).
ver(7).

edge(A, B):- reb(_, A, B); reb(_, B, A).

nonadjacency(A, B):-
    ver(A), ver(B), \+(edge(A, B)).

do(L) :-
 findall((A, B), nonadjacency(A, B), L), write(L), nl.


dfs(From, To, _, [edge(From, To)]):-
  edge(From, To).
dfs(From, To, VisitedNodes, [(From, X)|TailPath]):-
  edge(From, X),
  not(member(X, VisitedNodes)),
  dfs(X, To, [From|VisitedNodes], TailPath).
```

I could only display a list of pairs of vertices not connected by edges. What to do next?

Comment: empty subgraphs here are 145, 146, 147, 245, 246, 247, 35, 36, 37. the length of the largest of them is 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Largest empty subgraph of an undirected graph in SWI Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754007/largest-empty-subgraph-of-an-undirected-graph-in-swi-prolog)